# please help me with google admob service

Tags: android

Before i have used google admob sdk for integrate admob on android.
But now i want to try to integrate admob with google admob service.
But when admob appears,other background are not appeared.
If you have known its reason,please inform me.

This is my code.

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
adview = new Adview(this);
adView.setAdUnitId(admobid);
adview.setAdsize(Adsize.banner);
Linearlayout layout = (Linearlayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id = "@+id/mainLayout">


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is your ads displayed in full screen?? May be you have added it dynamically yo Linear layout which height is match_parent.

Comment: try  this link

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
adview = new Adview(this);
adView.setAdUnitId(admobid);
adview.setAdsize(Adsize.banner);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50);
adview.setLayoutParams(lp);
Linearlayout layout = (Linearlayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
layout.addView(adView);
AdRequest adrequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Comment: thanks for your help.But the result is same.

Comment: My project is cocos2dx-2.2.2 project.I've port cocos2d-x project to android project using jni.If you have experience of integrare admob to cocos2d-x 2.2 project,please inform me.Additionally,i can integrate admob with admob sdk in cocos2dx 2.1.It runs well,but in this project ,it is very difficult,when admob shows ,game screen doest not appear,other wise admob is not appear and game screen is appeared.